# resetting an iframe when closing the iframe window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, reload, reset

when I click on a box on my webpage another box appears; this is my `iframe`. 
When I click out of the `iframe` and back onto the webpage, I want my `iframe` to reload, so the next time I'll open it, it will start over from the beginning.

the `js` code looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("videoframe").contentWindow.step1();
```

The js code is referring to step1 which is an animation inside the `iframe`

Hope this makes sense.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used a trick to do that. When you remove the src of an Iframe and attach it again the iframes resets:

```
//save url
        var url = jQuery('#videoframe').attr('src');
//remove src
        jQuery('#videoframe').attr('src', '');
//reattach src
        jQuery('#videoframe').attr('src', url);
```